# sass-watch: command not found whenever I run sass-watch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I have Ruby and sass installed already, but I'm getting a

> sass-watch: command not found

Whenever I run

```
sass-watch .
```

Any ideas?

Comment: sass-watch is wrong command. sass is a gem, "--watch" is sass option.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sass --watch` instead of your command.

The CLI (command line) you have installed with `gem install sass` can be use with `sass` command.
So, `sass-watch` it's different for you console, and that's why it fails.

`sass --help` to have all commands informations ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the command correctly.

For example...

```
sass --watch assets/sass/main.scss:assets/css/main.css
```

Then SASS will create the map file within CSS folder as the main.css file.